Возможно ли сделать бота телеграм который забанит всех в чате?
Пытался сделать через ChatGPT бота в тг который банил бы всех участников, сам пытался сделать и понять как такое возможно, но ничего не вышло. Может быть есть какая то библиотека кроме python-telegram-bot в которой есть функция позволяющая отсканировать всех участников и забанить всех?

В Bot API нет такого метода. Нужно знать их id, а для это либо записывать куда-то, а потом доставать, либо использовать юзербот на telethon или pyrogram
